# How to change Doctrine ORM default tracking policy to Deferred Explicit

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using Doctrine ORM with symfony for my latest project. I need my doctrine to use Deferred Explicit tracking policy by default - I need to control what and when to save.

I can change doctrine tracking policy for each entity in its annotations

```
/**
* @ORM\ChangeTrackingPolicy("DEFERRED_EXPLICIT")
*/
```

but I would like to make this tracking policy default for all entities. I don't want to create a common parent entity just because of this. Is there any way to set this tracking policy default for a whole project?

About doctrine [tracking policies](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html).

Tanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

There is a `Doctrine\ORM\Events::loadClassMetadata` event, that you can hook into and create a listener that overwrites the policy in entity metadata.

The listener is called after metadata are loaded from annotations/yml/xml, before they're saved in cache, so it should be very effective.

- [Events: Lifecycle Events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events)
- [Events: Load ClassMetadata Event](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#load-classmetadata-event)
- [Symfony: How to Register Event Listeners and Subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

Here's some working code:

```
class DoctrineTrackingPolicySubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::loadClassMetadata
        ];
    }

    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $args)
    {
        $classMetadata = $args->getClassMetadata();
        $classMetadata->setChangeTrackingPolicy(
            ClassMetadataInfo::CHANGETRACKING_DEFERRED_EXPLICIT
        );
    }
}
```

Then in `services.yaml` or `services.yml`:

```
App\EventSubscriber\DoctrineTrackingPolicySubscriber:
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

For Symfony versions < 3.3 specifying a `class` will be necessary, newer versions implicitly assume service name is FQCN.

Comment: This means you will change entity tracking policy for each class on the fly (but not for each instance). That is acceptable solution, I will give it a few days, if someone finds something more obvious (like a doctrine settings). Thank you anyway - Díky Filipe :)

Comment: Note that using the Load ClassMetadata Event will let your override the specified Change Tracking policy for any entity, but it will not work to change the default policy when the entity does not otherwise specify.

Comment: It's better to use listener instead of subscriber as the subscriber has to always be instantiated even if not used while listener is instantiated only when actually needed (talking about doctrine subscribers, symfony subscribers behave differently).

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin Symfony recently introduced support for lazy doctrine subscribers

Comment: @FilipProcházka Can't find it anywhere, care to share a link?

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin turns out you're correct. Someone was tweeting that the listeners are lazy by default now and I've confused the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default change tracking policy from **Deferred Implicit** to **Deferred Explicit** by defining your own factory for constructing `\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata`.

This method still allows your for your configuration to specify either, and otherwise only impacts where you configuration does not specify otherwise.

```
<?php

class MyClassMetadataFactory extends Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function newClassMetadataInstance($className)
    {
        $classMetadata = parent::newClassMetadataInstance($className);

        // Change the default Change Tracking Policy to Deferred Explicit.
        $classMetadata->setChangeTrackingPolicy(
            Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo::CHANGETRACKING_DEFERRED_EXPLICIT
        );

        return $classMetadata;
    }
}

$xmlMetadataConfig = \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration([__DIR__ . '/config']);

// Set your class to be the factory for ClassMetadata.
$xmlMetadataConfig->setClassMetadataFactoryName(MyClassMetadataFactory::class);

$em = Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create(
    ['pdo' => $pdo],
    $xmlMetadataConfig
);
```

The key elements of this strategy are the following.

- Override `\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory::newClassMetadataInstance()` to change the properties of the constructed instance of `\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata`.
- Set your class as the factory to be used in the configuration of the Metadata Driver.

Comment: This require overriding classes that are not meant to be overriden and extremely sensitive to performance. Using a listener achieves the same and more cleanly, because the listener is meant as an extension point.

Comment: @FilipProcházka - hooking into the event listener does not provide a way to change the **default** policy for entities (please demonstrate if I'm wrong.) I'm also a little dubious of the argument that the class is not meant to be overridden when Doctrine provides it as a configuration option when construction the entity manager.

Comment: You're technically correct (insert technically correct meme here), but the listener achieves the same result and my main argument - more cleanly, since it's dedicated extension point. The class can be overridden, but IMHO it should be avoided when possible.

Answer (score -1):

My current solution is just a little more annoying than changing tracking policy project-wide - I have to always pass all my changed entities to [EntityManager->flush($entity=null)](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#338-359). In other words - I have to prevent calling flush method without parameters.